# Linear dependence/independence of functions $f(x) = x^2+1$, $g(x) = 1+x^3$ and $h(x) = \ln(1 + x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Questions :**

Prove that the functions $f(x) = x^2+1$, $g(x) = 1+x^3$ and $h(x) = \ln(1 + x)$ are linearly independent on the interval $(0, 1)$. Can you use the Wronskian to do this?

**I try this:**
$$c_1 x f(x)+ c_2 x g(x) + c_3 x h(x) = 0.$$
but I don't know how to solve for the values of $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wronskian is \begin{align}W(f,g,h)(x)&=\begin{vmatrix}f(x)& g(x) & h(x)\\f'(x) & g'(x) & h'(x) \\f''(x) & g''(x)& h''(x)\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1+x^2& 1+x^3 & \ln{(1+x)}\\2x & 3x^2 & \frac1{1+x} \\2 & 6x & -\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\end{vmatrix}\\[0.3cm]&=\left\{\text{terms without} \ln(x+1)\right\}+6x^2\ln(x+1)\end{align} which means that the Wronskian does not vanish, hence the functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 3):

Why $c_1 x f(x)+ c_2 x g(x) + c_3 x h(x) = 0$ ?

You have to show that from

$(*)$ $c_1 f(x)+ c_2  g(x) + c_3  h(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1)$

it follows that $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$.

From $(*)$ it follows by continuity:

$c_1 f(x)+ c_2  g(x) + c_3  h(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ .

Now let $x=0$, $x=1$ and $x=1/2$, then you get a very easy linear system for the coefficients $c_i$.

It is your turn to show:  $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=x^2+1$$

$$h(x)=1=x^3$$

$$h(x)=\ln(1+x)$$

$$c_1xf(x)+c_2xg(x)+c_3xh(x)=0$$

Dividing through $x$,

We have got

$$c_1f(x)+c_2g(x)+c_3h(x)=0$$

There is a theorem states that if the constants

$$c_1=c_2=c_3=0$$

it follows that the vector is linearly independent.

$$c_1(x^2+1)+c_2(1+x^3)+c_3(\ln(1+x))=0$$

$$c_1x^2+c_2x^3+c_1+c_2+c_3\ln(1+x)=0$$

It is obvious that the trivial solution is

$$c_1=c_2=c_3=0$$

since

the coefficients of $x^2$ which is $c_1=0$. The argument for the rest also follows.